# C# Entity Framework Core store enum using native enum datatype

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, enums

I am using Entity Framework Code with Code First development approach and a PostgreSQL Database. One of my classes has a enum property. This works out quite well.

However, when I took a look at the database I noticed that in the database the enum was actually stored as an integer, not as an enum as I had expected. So if you now directly query data from the database, you only see the integer and you have no clue what it means.

I have seen [here](https://codewithshadman.com/entity-framework-enum-code-first/) and [here](https://medium.com/agilix/entity-framework-core-enums-ee0f8f4063f2) that you can use a lookup table or store the enum as string to circumvent this, but this seems a bit unnatural IMHO, considering that you could also just could store the enum in the database.

So is there any way to store enums as [enum datatype](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-enum.html) in the database? If no, why not?

Comment: You can select between int and string in db. https://medium.com/agilix/entity-framework-core-enums-ee0f8f4063f2

Comment: @RoarS. Yes, but I can't find anywhere if you can also store the enum as enum datatype in the database. I want to know if that's possible.

Comment: I don't think it's supported because the enum datatype is vendor-specific.

Comment: I'm with @GertArnold on this one; I've never seen something like enum type in db before, and I've been in the business for 25 years :-)

Comment: "he enum was actually stored as an integer," - ah, enums native data types ARE integer style structs. A standard enum actually is an integer, unless you redefine it as byte or long or something like this.

Comment: @TomTom Yes, but I don't want a random integer in my database. I'd like to store the enum in the database (as PostgreSQL enum) and then have a enum column in my database table referring to the previously declared enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check the https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-enum.html for the enum type in postgres sql db, as for ef core,
can use `modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum("schema", "typename", new[] { "enum1", "enum2" })`, to let efcore know what to do for the enum type, the refences is here https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html?tabs=tabid-1

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!